# Data transformations with RxJava in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I'm using Kotlin and I have an `Observable<List<FlickPhoto>>` model. Each `FlickrPhoto` contains a List, and each `Photos` model contains a `List<Photo>`.

I want to transform a `List<FlickrPhoto>` to a `List<PhotoEntity>`, which is basically another model with less data, and wrap it into an `Observable` (in order to finally get an `Observable<List<PhotoEntity>>`).

How can I do this in the best RxJava way?
I have created a `PhotoEntityMapper` class with the following method that I'm sure could be properly used for the purpose:
`override fun transform(photoCollection: List<Photo>): List<PhotoEntity>`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe something like this would work: `remoteDataSource.
                getPhotos(photoTag)
                .flatMap({ t: FlickrPhoto -> Observable.just(serviceMapper.transform(t.photos.photo)) })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in your comment does work:

```
// original
remoteDataSource
    .getPhotos(photoTag)
    .flatMap({ t: FlickrPhoto -> 
        Observable
            .just(serviceMapper.transform(t.photos.photo)) // <-- not lazy
    })
```

Here you have slightly different options:

```
// v1
remoteDataSource
    .getPhotos(photoTag)
    .flatMap {
        Observable
            .just(it.photos.photo)
            .map { serviceMapper.transform(it) }  // <-- lazy transformation
    }

// v2
remoteDataSource
    .getPhotos(photoTag)
    .flatMapIterable { it }
    .map { serviceMapper.transform(it.photos.photo) }
```

No option is that much better than the others. Normally I would go with `v2` because it is shorter.

But, I don't know what the `serviceMapper` does. For example, if it involved network and I wanted to execute it in another `Scheduler`, then `v1` is nice because you can subscribe the transformations in another thread (which you can't do in the original version because the transformation is pre-computed eaguerly). Example:

```
// v1 - with scheduler
remoteDataSource
    .getPhotos(photoTag)
    .flatMap {
        Observable
            .just(it.photos.photo)
            .map { serviceMapper.transform(it) } // <-- lazy transformation
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())        // <-- schedule on io()
    }
```